# Find next / previous number in mysql table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Given this table:

```
contractnumber | itemnumber
1234           | 100151
1234           | 100152
1235           | 100127
1235           | 100128
1236           | 100001
1236           | 100002
```

How can I get the next (or previous) itemnumber from the table after a given itemnumber with the table order is contractnumber ASC, itemnumber ASC?

For example I'd like to get the next itemnumber after 100128 (100128) or the previous itemnumber to 100001 (100128).

Comment: Use `LEAD`/`LAG`.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.30 (on ubuntu 18.04), too old for LEAD / LAG

Comment: Is itemnumber unique?

Comment: yes, itemnumber is unique

Comment: The question is confusing. Voting to close.

Comment: @TheImpaler: Your (deleted) answer seems to be the best for me. If it's unclear than please let me know so I can improve the question.

Comment: @jlai79 I know you already accepted the other answer, but in the interest of a shorter solution I adapted my answer to make use of the "unique itemnumber column", and I undeleted it, so you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.x you cannot use `LEAD()` or `LAG()`. However, you can order the rows and limit the result set to 1 row. See below

For the **next element** of `100128` you can use:

```
select *
from t
where (contractnumber, itemnumber) > (
  select contractnumber, itemnumber from t where itemnumber = 100128
)
order by contractnumber, itemnumber 
limit 1;
```

Result:

```
contractnumber  itemnumber
--------------  ----------
          1236      100001
```

For the **previous element** of `100128` you can use:

```
select *
from t
where (contractnumber, itemnumber) < (
  select contractnumber, itemnumber from t where itemnumber = 100128
)
order by contractnumber desc, itemnumber desc
limit 1;
```

Result:

```
contractnumber  itemnumber
--------------  ----------
          1235      100127
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/icmNND55d5b3r1hBz8xvci/1).

Comment: You use in your query the contractnumber  = 1235 which is not given.

Comment: This look good and easy but I have to get get the contractnumber first which is not a problem for me.

Comment: @jlai79 ...but you DO NEED to use the `contractnumber`, don't you? You are implying that is not necessary; that would mean that `itemnumber` is a unique key on the table. Is it so?

Comment: Now, if `itemnumber` is a key on the table, then the whole question doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question. I just didn't know I can do a "where (contractnumber, itemnumber) < ( x, y)"

Comment: @jlai79 That's called a "tuple inequality predicate" and is implemented in a few databases such as DB2, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, MySQL, H2, HyperSQL to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

Since for each `contractnumber` may exist different `itemnumber`s it's not as simple as `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.
You must also check the case that the next/previous `itemnumber` has the same `contractnumber`.

For the previous item of 100128:

```
select
  coalesce(
    (
      select min(itemnumber) from tablename 
      where contractnumber = (
        select contractnumber from tablename 
        where itemnumber = 100128
      ) and itemnumber > 100128
    ),
    (
      select itemnumber from tablename
      where contractnumber > (
        select contractnumber from tablename 
        where itemnumber = 100128
      )
      order by contractnumber, itemnumber limit 1
    )  
  ) itemnumber
```

For the next item of 100001:

```
select
  coalesce(
    (
      select max(itemnumber) from tablename 
      where contractnumber = (
        select contractnumber from tablename 
        where itemnumber = 100001
      ) and itemnumber < 100001
    ),
    (
      select itemnumber from tablename
      where contractnumber < (
        select contractnumber from tablename 
        where itemnumber = 100001
      )
      order by contractnumber desc, itemnumber desc limit 1
    )  
  ) itemnumber
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d5d702131477ff4fbbe5055e1fe84dca).

Comment: This seems to work but looks more complicated than the other solution by The Impaler.

Comment: If you mentioned that you know the contractnumber then it would not be complicated.

Comment: When itemnumber is unique you can easily select the contractnumber. I see that my question is not clear enough. sorry for that

Comment: This is why I use: `select contractnumber from tablename where itemnumber = ?` in my queries, to get the contractnumber of the itemnumber.